# Passing in specific return order for AWS Cloudsearch query

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

Is there a way that I am able to tell a cloudsearch query that I want to get the matching results back in a specific order?

I have cloudsearch populated with Products.
For each User, I have a predefined order that I want those products to appear.
The user can filter the Products by a number of fields, and this will call Cloudsearch and return the matches, 10 at a time (ajax loaded paged results)

How can I tell Cloudsearch that once it has found those matches, I want them to be returned in the predefined order for this particular customer?

Comment: Are you planning to index the order for each user in CloudSearch? How many users do you plan to have? Are there a fixed number of ordering schemes? Somehow CloudSearch is going to need to know what the ordering is if it's going to sort the results for you. Can the rank be derived based on other properties of the documents? If so just use a rank expression http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/configuring-expressions.html ; otherwise, you're going to need to index it but I can't give any more advice than that without knowing more about your requirements.

Comment: I would have over 100k Users, and each one of them would have their own bespoke ordering, so that would mean adding a new index for every single customer in CloudSearch, which isn't really feasible is it? 100k columns on a search object?

The ranking is based on a Third Party algorithm, and stored in a table locally in our DB. So we could send the order of IDs in our search query, if there was a way to tell CloudSearch to use this ordering of its results.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so it's infeasible to index the ranking for each user and I'm assuming the ranking is arbitrary and not something that could be expressed in a CloudSearch rank expression. Within the constraints you've set, I don't think there's a great way to do this.

The best I can come up with would be something like **getting *all* the results for a query** and then sorting them based on the ranking in your DB. CloudSearch is fairly fast and you should be able to request result sets of a few thousand (in my index of 40k docs, returning a set of 1000 results took ~400ms). You'd then have to sort those according to their rank in your datastore. It feels very wasteful but it may be the best you can do with the constraints you're working in.

Or you could **get the top n items for that user from your database**, and hit CloudSearch with the user's query, checking for those top n items in the results (this could actually be part of the query) and paging through search results until you've found enough (10 in your case) to display them to the user.

Given the inefficiency of the above solutions, I'd urge re-evaluating your constraints: **ranking search results should really be the responsibility of the search engine**; separating that responsibility, creates a messy handoff that ideally shouldn't exist. Maybe you can come up with a replacement for the third-party ranking algorithm that can be expressed as a rank expression; maybe you can do filtering in through your database queries instead of using cloudsearch.

Comment: Appreciate your comments, and I was already stuck down this road, hoping against hope that there was some magical solution that I didn't know about.

Comment: No prob. Sorry no silver bullet for this one. I wish you luck!